# Skydrive windows Phone 8 app - Image Url getting expired after few hours.

Tags: windows-phone-8, onedrive

I'm creating a SkyDrive photo viewer - a Windows Phone 8 app. When retrieving a photo URL from the SkyDrive API, it expires after few hours. I need to send this link to my print out department, so they can print and deliver it to the customer. I am getting URLs like this:

https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y3mk6fyb7lhibSzZuAjVOfj0UL4mB1EnJOX8Xbu1VtLasYTElmS-Rya3Sd6321IYkpQkG5gRGIcZ7s3a7uzUe_hN5fg/WP_20130613_001.jpg?psid=1&ck=0&ex=720.

How can I get an unexpired URL from SkyDrive API? I am using Microsoft Live Controls.

Answer (score 1):

[SkyDrive URLs expire (after some time) by design](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/9f00e21e-45ad-430d-9aa1-1d63cfe2d24f/sky-drive-continuously-changing-url), this is done intentionally to avoid abuse and misuse of the service.
An API for Skydrive has been created but I don't really know if its useful and/or safe; I just read the referred links.
More information about the [SkyScraper API](http://www.timacheson.com/Blog/2009/oct/skydrive_api) created by Tim Acheson can be found in his website.
Hope other users report on this.